# Variations in a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Let be $M$ a Riemannian  manifold and $X,Y$ vector fields over $M.$ 
Now take $p\in M$ arbitrarily,  my question is, how construc a variation $f:U\to M,$
 $$U\subset \mathbb{R}^2,~~U=\{-\epsilon<t<1+\epsilon,~~-\epsilon<s<1+\epsilon, ~~\epsilon>0\}$$
satisfying $f(s,0)=f(0,0)$ for all $s, $ such that

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}(0,1)=X(p),~~~\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial s}(0,1)= Y(p)~~~~~~ ??$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a totally convex neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$ and choose $q\in U$ such that the unique geodesic $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ joinning $q$ to $p$ satisfies
$$\gamma(1)=p$$
$$\gamma'(1)=X(p).$$
Moreover, there exists $v\in T_qM$ such that $\exp_q(v)=\gamma(1)$. We have that $\exp_q$ is a diffeomorphism of some neighborhood of $0\in T_qM$ onto $U$. Then, there exists $Y\in T_v(T_qM)$ such that
$$d(\exp_q)_v(Y)=Y(p)$$
Consider the curve $c(t)=v+tY$ in $T_qM$ and the variation
$$f(s,t)=\exp_q(t\cdot c(s))$$
We have by definition that $\partial_tf(0,1)=\gamma'(1)=X(p)$. We have, at the same time,
\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_sf(0,1)&=&\frac{d}{ds}f(s,1)_{s=0}\\
&=&\frac{d}{ds}\exp_q(c(s))_{s=0}\\
&=&d(\exp_q)_{c(0)}\cdot c'(0)\\
&=&d(\exp_q)_v\cdot Y\\
&=&Y(p)
\end{eqnarray}